# Multiple Attributes in KMZ

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, kmz

I have shapefiles that I ended up having multiple attributes for and I ended up getting 3 group folders that hold different lines on the KMZ.  The groups are for gas lines 0-20 pressure 20-60 and then 60+.  Inside these groups are sections of line that are 20, 30, 45... etc.  Because of this, I want to be able to click on the line in KMZ and have it say "LayerName - XXX PSI".  When I try to do this within QGIS I end up getting rid of the attributes and it is not smart any more. As shown in the picture I already have the Layer as the the name but I want to be able to have the DesignPres attribute next to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this approach:

- create a field (myfield) which holds the layer name and the attribute you want to display alongside with the field calculator with this:

  ```
  concat(  @layer_name , '_',"DesignPres", '_some other string')
  ```
- when exporting the layer from QGIS with "save as.." set the NameField attribute to myfield as in screenshot 1

[image]

- the result looks like this:

[image]

I have tested this with QGIS 2.14.15